# Ubuntu server doesn't handle SFTP/SCP connection

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, filezilla, winscp

I've installed FTP on Ubuntu 14.04 server and I tried to connect to it via FileZilla. It works if I use FTP. But if I try to connect via SFTP, there are no folders or files shown, and I get the error:

```
Error:  Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I tried with WinSCP and it attempted to connect, but it just closed the program and opened the connection options dialog up again.
How do I get secure file transfer working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[File Transfer Protocol (FTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) and [Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) are different protocols. If you want to connect to the system via SFTP, also, you will need to install SSH server software on the Ubuntu system. Also, in case you aren't aware, SFTP and [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), which provides encryption capabilities for the FTP protocol, are also different protocols. WinSCP supports [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) and [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) and you will need to select the appropriate protocol for a session in the "file protocol" field prior to attempting a connection depending on which protocol you wish to use to connect.